# Printing a dataframe to a telegram bot using r

Tags: r, r-telegram-bot

When sending data to print out in the telegram chat, using telegram bot in r, I found that the message should be constructed into a variable using sprintf.

I tried to send a dataframe directly with no luck. So I used the basic implementation:

```
textOut = sprintf("What ever I want to send to the chat")
bot$sendMessage(chat_id = update$message$chat_id,
                   text =  textOut)
```

Is there a way to send a dataframe straight to the bot and get a "fairly" nice printout of it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The `kable()` function in the knitr package will render a data.frame as markdown, which might be one approach?

```r
> knitr::kable(head(mtcars[, 1:4]), "pipe")
```

```
|                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp|
|:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|---:|
|Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110|
|Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6|  160| 110|
|Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4|  108|  93|
|Hornet 4 Drive    | 21.4|   6|  258| 110|
|Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8|  360| 175|
|Valiant           | 18.1|   6|  225| 105|
```

Comment: Does not render the full table. Only the column headers. I've already tried it some time ago and couldn't make it work.